# Purpose of flexGrow in the parent div of a Material UI grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I'm trying to understand this code example, https://codesandbox.io/s/9rvlm, from the examples in the Material UI docs (https://material-ui.com/components/grid/):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
});

function CenteredGrid(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

CenteredGrid.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CenteredGrid);
```

My question is: what is the purpose of assigning `flexGrow: 1` to the parent `div` element?

As I understand from https://material-ui.com/system/flexbox/#flex-grow and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow, `flex-grow` is a CSS property of items of flex containers. In this example though, I don't see there being a flex container element containing this component; the `CenteredGrid` is displayed (as `<Demo/>`) directly in the root div.

Are the `styles.root` applied to the parent div 'just in case' the component is rendered in a flex container? I'd appreciate some clarification.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think there's a point to it being there. The only time it would make a difference is when there is a flex parent.

Answer (score 4):

The comment by Anthony mentioned above seems the right answer to me. If the parent is set to display:flex and child component being loaded does not have flex:1 or flex-grow:1 then it will not take up 100% width of the parent.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="border:1px solid black; padding:2px; ">
    <div style="border:1px solid red; ">parent is not flex container - child div takes 100% width</div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div style="border:1px solid black; padding:2px; ">
    <div style="border:1px solid red; flex-grow:1; ">parent is not flex container - child div takes 100% width</div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div style="border:1px solid black; padding:2px; display:flex; ">
    <div style="border:1px solid red; ">parent is flex container - sorry</div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div style="border:1px solid black; padding:2px; display:flex; ">
    <div style="border:1px solid red; display:flex; flex-grow:1;">parent is flex container - child div takes 100%</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment of AnthonyZ said:

> The only time it would make a difference is when there is a flex
> parent.

But in a React App the outer Div in the Body is not the outer-most parent.
In HTML/CSS that is the HTML and the BODY.
In a create-react-app they get the default "display:block" in either index.css or base stylesheet (of the browser).

I solved it by doing the following:

### Move index.css to public

> Seriously, why is index.css in /src and index.html in /public ??

### Modify index.css

Specify "display:flex" for both HTML and BODY in index.css

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

### Modify App.js

In App.js create an outer div

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
}));

// ....

function App() {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <TopMenu/>
                    <AllRoutes/>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

### TopMenu.js

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    offset: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    
    title: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
}));


export default function TopMenu() {
    
    const classes = useStyles();
    
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <AppBar position="fixed">
                <Toolbar variant='dense'>
                    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                        Application Title
                    </Typography>
                    <MainMenu/>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <div className={classes.offset}/>
        </React.Fragment>

    );
}
```

If you inspect the elements, you'll see that the whole height is taken started from the HTML-tag.

Problem with this solution: That annoying scrollbar which takes lets you scroll the height of the AppBar.
If somebody has a solution for that, I'll edit my answer (or delete the answer when there's a far better solution :-) )